# Get color values in byte stream- ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdata

I read this byte stream from a binary file (.ase) Bold values represent colors:

<41534546 00010000 00000005 c0010000 00140008 004f0070 0061006c 0074006f 006e0065 00000001 00000024 00080023 00320042 00420034 00300046 00005247 4220**3e2c acad3f34 b4b53d70 f0f1**0002 00010000 00240008 00230046 00460035 00420033 00310000 52474220 **3f800000 3eb6b6b7 3e44c4c5** 00020001 00000024 00080023 00460046 00380037 00340038 00005247 4220**3f80 00003f07 87883e90 9091**0002 00010000 00240008 00230030 00330038 00340043 00410000 52474220 **3c40c0c1 3f048485 3f4acacb** 0002>

If color `9BD6AE` was there byte chunk will be **3f1b9b9c 3f56d6d7 3f2eaeaf**

Each block represents the float values of each color component. (red:0.607843 green:0.839216 blue:0.682353)

How do I get those float values from the above data stream?

Comment: ASE (Adobe Swatch Exchange) Encoder
http://blog.soulwire.co.uk/code/actionscript-3/as3-ase-adobe-swatch-exchange-encoder

Comment: Can you provide more information about the input format? Are there a constant number of bytes before and after the ones you're interested in? If not, do you have a heuristic for identifying the bytes you want? Or do you know exactly how to get the data and you just need help implementing your procedure in Objective-C? Please post what you've written so far.

Comment: @bdesham : In my above comment i have a put a link to ASE file generation algo. You can find ASE file format specification in http://www.selapa.net/swatches/colors/fileformats.php#adobe_ase . i want to read colors from those .ase file.

Comment: color values  are always presented between(52474220 &0002)  : { 52474220 [ color values ] 0002 }. <41534546 00010 bla bla  **  represent files headers and length etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have NSData with the contents of the file, you can convert those values to `float` with code like the following:

```
NSData *data = ... // contents of the ASE file
const void *bytes = [data bytes];
int offset = ... // offset into the data stream (in bytes)

// assuming offset is pointing to the start of 4 bytes that represent a float value:
float colorComponent = [self floatFromBytes:bytes + offset];


// Helper method to convert bytes to a float
// In ASE file, float values are 4-byte values in big-endian format
- (float)floatFromBytes:(const void *)bytes {
    uint_32_t beVal = *(uint_32_t *)bytes; // data is in big-endian format
    uint_32_t locVal = CFSwapInt32BigToHost(beVal); // data in host format

    float res = *(float *)&locVal; // convert bytes to float

    return res;
}
```

This is far from a full ASE parsing algorithm. But this shows how to convert 4-byte values into `float` values. You need to deal with lots of other aspects of the ASE file format.