# How to convert NSString with hex values to Char - Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, hex

I have a NSString @"460046003600430035003900" which represent hex color FF6C59.

How can i get that hex color from strings in above format:

eg:
460046003500430032003000 = FF5C20

300030004200350033004500 = 00B53E

Comment: How does `"460046003600430035003900"` represent `FF6C59`?

Comment: FF6C59 in decimal should be 16739417, in binary 111111110110110001011001, in octal 77666131. Kindly tell your base by which 460046003600430035003900 comes.

Comment: Looks like the '00' are useless. So if you take them out, you wind up with 46 46 36 43 35 39, which are the respective ASCII hex codes for F F 6 C 5 9. Weird encoding, but that's what it looks like.

Comment: Looks like some totally garbled Unicode conversion (the zero characters every other byte) or similar. Are you sure that there is not an earlier step where you can intervene to get the string values right?

Comment: Guys please check : http://www.asciitable.com/
hex 46 represent char F
hex 30 represent char 0
hex 36 represent char 6 likewise 
but i have those hex values in a string

Comment: Is it a UTF-32 encoding of the hex value as a string?

Comment: @rmaddy : i read these values from .ASE file. How can i get string "FF6C59" from @"460046003600430035003900"

Comment: @dileepa88 : You need to make an algo, either componentsSeparatedBySring:@"00" (which will fail when yuo have a value 00 for hex) or save each pairs of values in an array, and convert them to hex.

Comment: @AKV: is there any easy way to convert them to hex. i mean "46" to "F", "36" to "6" etc..

Comment: @dileepa88: 46 would be 2E, isn't it from http://www.asciitable.com/

Comment: @AKV : 46 is in ASCII hex format. which represent char "F". 46 46 36 43 35 39, which are the respective ASCII hex codes for F F 6 C 5 9.

Comment: @dileepa88 if you need to parse an ASE file then why do you load the file into a string? Load the file into NSData and read the bytes as needed.

Comment: @dileepa88 See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14880570/get-color-values-in-byte-stream-ios

Comment: @rmaddy : ya that was my question :) i was unable to locate required bytes in NSData reads from ASE file. So i thought try in this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface WeirdFormatDecoder : NSObject
@end

@implementation WeirdFormatDecoder

+(NSString*) decode:(NSString*)string
{
    if (!string) return @"";
    NSAssert([string length]%2==0, @"bad format");
    NSMutableString *s = [NSMutableString new];
    for (NSUInteger i=0; i<[string length]-2; i=i+2) {
        char c = [[string substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(i, 2)] integerValue];
        if (c==0) continue;
        else if (c<41){
            [s appendFormat:@"%c",[@"0123456789" characterAtIndex:c-30]];
        } else {
            [s appendFormat:@"%c",[@"ABCDEF" characterAtIndex:c-41]];
        }
    }
    return s;
}

@end

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSLog(@"%@",[WeirdFormatDecoder decode:@"460046003600430035003900"]); // FF6C59
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that really is what you're getting, and you're not doing something to further obfuscate it, set up a loop to chop the string into 2-byte strings.  Ignore every other 2-byte combo.  Treat the non-ignored values as hex and convert to int, resulting in the value of an ASCII char.  Do standard hex conversion on the char value to convert to a 0..15 int value.  Accumulate the int values as 4 bit quantities in an int.

So you've got to do hex->int conversion twice.